# error serving django on apache2 with mod_wsgi: No module named settings

Tags: python, django, apache, http, mod-wsgi

The error log on restart with 1 request, for some reason it seems to be failing to load the "middleware"? for the settings, and the settings file in general. Could this have to do with permissions or just my configuration somehow?

```
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:42 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/2.8 Python/2.6.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252] mod_wsgi (pid=6165): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/srv/www/quickerhub.com/interest/django.wsgi'.
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]     self.load_middleware()
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]     self._setup(name)
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]     raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252] ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252] mod_wsgi (pid=6166): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/srv/www/quickerhub.com/interest/django.wsgi'.
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]     self.load_middleware()
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]     self._setup(name)
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252]     raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
[Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252] ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings
```

my file structure:

```
.
├── logfile
└── srv
    ├── logfile
    └── www
        └── quickerhub.com
            ├── admin
            │   ├── css
            │   │   ├── base.css
            │   │   ├── changelists.css
            │   │   ├── dashboard.css
            │   │   ├── forms.css
            │   │   ├── ie.css
            │   │   ├── login.css
            │   │   ├── rtl.css
            │   │   └── widgets.css
            │   ├── img
            │   │   ├── changelist-bg.gif
            │   │   ├── changelist-bg_rtl.gif
            │   │   ├── chooser-bg.gif
            │   │   ├── chooser_stacked-bg.gif
            │   │   ├── default-bg.gif
            │   │   ├── default-bg-reverse.gif
            │   │   ├── deleted-overlay.gif
            │   │   ├── gis
            │   │   │   ├── move_vertex_off.png
            │   │   │   └── move_vertex_on.png
            │   │   ├── icon_addlink.gif
            │   │   ├── icon_alert.gif
            │   │   ├── icon_calendar.gif
            │   │   ├── icon_changelink.gif
            │   │   ├── icon_clock.gif
            │   │   ├── icon_deletelink.gif
            │   │   ├── icon_error.gif
            │   │   ├── icon-no.gif
            │   │   ├── icon_searchbox.png
            │   │   ├── icon_success.gif
            │   │   ├── icon-unknown.gif
            │   │   ├── icon-yes.gif
            │   │   ├── inline-delete-8bit.png
            │   │   ├── inline-delete.png
            │   │   ├── inline-restore-8bit.png
            │   │   ├── inline-restore.png
            │   │   ├── inline-splitter-bg.gif
            │   │   ├── nav-bg.gif
            │   │   ├── nav-bg-grabber.gif
            │   │   ├── nav-bg-reverse.gif
            │   │   ├── nav-bg-selected.gif
            │   │   ├── selector-icons.gif
            │   │   ├── selector-search.gif
            │   │   ├── sorting-icons.gif
            │   │   ├── tool-left.gif
            │   │   ├── tool-left_over.gif
            │   │   ├── tool-right.gif
            │   │   ├── tool-right_over.gif
            │   │   ├── tooltag-add.gif
            │   │   ├── tooltag-add_over.gif
            │   │   ├── tooltag-arrowright.gif
            │   │   └── tooltag-arrowright_over.gif
            │   └── js
            │       ├── actions.js
            │       ├── actions.min.js
            │       ├── admin
            │       │   ├── DateTimeShortcuts.js
            │       │   ├── ordering.js
            │       │   └── RelatedObjectLookups.js
            │       ├── calendar.js
            │       ├── collapse.js
            │       ├── collapse.min.js
            │       ├── core.js
            │       ├── getElementsBySelector.js
            │       ├── inlines.js
            │       ├── inlines.min.js
            │       ├── jquery.init.js
            │       ├── jquery.js
            │       ├── jquery.min.js
            │       ├── LICENSE-JQUERY.txt
            │       ├── prepopulate.js
            │       ├── prepopulate.min.js
            │       ├── SelectBox.js
            │       ├── SelectFilter2.js
            │       ├── timeparse.js
            │       └── urlify.js
            ├── interest
            │   ├── django.wsgi
            │   ├── __init__.py
            │   ├── __init__.pyc
            │   ├── settings.py
            │   ├── settings.pyc
            │   ├── urls.py
            │   └── wsgi.py
            ├── js
            │   └── jquery-1.10.1.min.js
            ├── logfile
            ├── manage.py
            ├── README
            ├── reoccurring
            │   ├── admin.py
            │   ├── forms.py
            │   ├── __init__.py
            │   ├── __init__.pyc
            │   ├── models.py
            │   ├── models.pyc
            │   ├── usagelib.py
            │   └── views.py
            ├── schedule
            │   ├── admin.py
            │   ├── __init__.py
            │   ├── __init__.pyc
            │   ├── models.py
            │   ├── models.pyc
            │   ├── tests.py
            │   ├── usagelib.py
            │   └── views.py
            ├── src
            │   ├── facebooksdk
            │   │   ├── examples
            │   │   │   ├── appengine
            │   │   │   │   ├── app.yaml
            │   │   │   │   ├── example.html
            │   │   │   │   └── example.py
            │   │   │   ├── newsfeed
            │   │   │   │   ├── app.yaml
            │   │   │   │   ├── facebookclient.py
            │   │   │   │   ├── static
            │   │   │   │   │   ├── base.css
            │   │   │   │   │   ├── favicon.ico
            │   │   │   │   │   └── robots.txt
            │   │   │   │   └── templates
            │   │   │   │       ├── base.html
            │   │   │   │       ├── home.html
            │   │   │   │       └── index.html
            │   │   │   ├── oauth
            │   │   │   │   ├── app.yaml
            │   │   │   │   ├── facebookoauth.py
            │   │   │   │   └── oauth.html
            │   │   │   └── tornado
            │   │   │       ├── example.html
            │   │   │       ├── example.py
            │   │   │       └── schema.sql
            │   │   ├── facebook.py
            │   │   ├── facebook_sdk.egg-info
            │   │   │   ├── dependency_links.txt
            │   │   │   ├── PKG-INFO
            │   │   │   ├── SOURCES.txt
            │   │   │   └── top_level.txt
            │   │   ├── MANIFEST.in
            │   │   ├── README.rst
            │   │   └── setup.py
            │   └── pip-delete-this-directory.txt
            ├── static
            │   └── js
            │       └── jquery-1.10.1.min.js
            ├── templates
            │   ├── 404.html
            │   ├── 500.html
            │   ├── Base.html
            │   ├── Home.html
            │   ├── Reoccurring.html
            │   └── Usersettings.html
            └── usersetting
                ├── admin.py
                ├── __init__.py
                ├── __init__.pyc
                ├── models.py
                ├── models.pyc
                └── views.py
```

my django.wsgi: EDITED

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/srv/www/quickerhub.com/')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'interest.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

my httpd.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/quickerhub.com/interest/django.wsgi

<Directory /srv/www/quickerhub.com>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

my sites-enabled/quickerhub.com:

```
WSGIPythonPath /srv/www/quickerhub.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName quickerhub.com
    ServerAlias testing.quickerhub.com

    Alias /static/ /srv/www/quickerhub.com/interest/static/
    # Alias /sitemap.xml /srv/www/quickerhub.com/interest/static/sitemap.xml
    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/quickerhub.com/interest/django.wsgi

    <Directory />
        AllowOverride None
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/quickerhub.com/.git/>
        Deny From All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: your `settings` is under `interest` but you do not have this path in the `sys.path`. do you?

Answer (score 0):

```
sys.path.append(rootpathofyoursite)
```

My wsgi file is in the root path of my site, so I cheat:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))))
```

Comment: Why not just `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`?

Comment: this fixed all of my errors, but I am now receiving a 500 error, with no errors in the apache log at all

Comment: Good point Daniil. I wrote it when I was newer to python, and it's always worked, so I've just left it.

Comment: Make sure to `import sys, os, inspect`

Comment: I turned debug on and recieved `sys.stdout access restricted by mod_wsgi` and proceeded to turn off wsgi restriction, and now the server is unresponsive..

Comment: If you get that restricted error, you are using a very old mod_wsgi version. Consider upgrading. Consider go reading up on daemon mode and also setting WSGIApplicationGroup to %{GLOBAL} to avoid deadlocks due to broken third party extensions that will not work in sub interpreters.